# How to set Alarm t Start Service in DialogPreference

Tags: android, alarmmanager, dialog-preference

I am using a Custom DialogPreference but I want to start a service when user sets the time.. i.e start a alarmmanager to work.. But when I type my code in onTimeSet() method it does not allow to add alarm service there.

```
public class Timer extends DialogPreference {
    protected int lastHour=0;
    protected int lastMinute=0;
    protected boolean is24HourFormat;
    protected TimePicker picker=null;
    protected TextView timeDisplay;

    DatagramPacket send;
    DatagramSocket d1;
    InetAddress ip;

    public Timer(Context ctxt) {
        this(ctxt, null);
    }

    public Timer(Context ctxt, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(ctxt, attrs, 0);
    }

    public Timer(Context ctxt, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(ctxt, attrs, defStyle);

        is24HourFormat = DateFormat.is24HourFormat(ctxt);
        setPositiveButtonText("Set");
        setNegativeButtonText("Cancel");
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        if(is24HourFormat) {
            return ((lastHour < 10) ? "0" : "")
                    + Integer.toString(lastHour)
                    + ":" + ((lastMinute < 10) ? "0" : "")
                    + Integer.toString(lastMinute);
        } else {
            int myHour = lastHour % 12;
            return ((myHour == 0) ? "12" : ((myHour < 10) ? "0" : "") + Integer.toString(myHour))
                    + ":" + ((lastMinute < 10) ? "0" : "") 
                    + Integer.toString(lastMinute) 
                    + ((lastHour >= 12) ? " PM" : " AM");
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected View onCreateDialogView() {
        picker=new TimePicker(getContext().getApplicationContext());
        return(picker);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onBindDialogView(View v) {
        super.onBindDialogView(v);
        picker.setIs24HourView(is24HourFormat);
        picker.setCurrentHour(lastHour);
        picker.setCurrentMinute(lastMinute);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindView(View view) {
        View widgetLayout;
        int childCounter = 0;
        do {
            widgetLayout = ((ViewGroup) view).getChildAt(childCounter);
            childCounter++;
        } while (widgetLayout.getId() != android.R.id.widget_frame); 
        ((ViewGroup) widgetLayout).removeAllViews();
        timeDisplay = new TextView(widgetLayout.getContext());
        timeDisplay.setText(toString());
        ((ViewGroup) widgetLayout).addView(timeDisplay);
        super.onBindView(view);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDialogClosed(boolean positiveResult) {
        super.onDialogClosed(positiveResult);

        if (positiveResult) {
            picker.clearFocus();
            lastHour=picker.getCurrentHour();
            lastMinute=picker.getCurrentMinute();

            String time=String.valueOf(lastHour)+":"+String.valueOf(lastMinute);

            if (callChangeListener(time)) {
                persistString(time);
                timeDisplay.setText(toString());




            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected Object onGetDefaultValue(TypedArray a, int index) {
        return(a.getString(index));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSetInitialValue(boolean restoreValue, Object defaultValue) {
        String time=null;

        if (restoreValue) {
            if (defaultValue==null) {
                time=getPersistedString("00:00");
            }
            else {
                time=getPersistedString(defaultValue.toString());
            }
        }
        else {
            if (defaultValue==null) {
                time="00:00";
            }
            else {
                time=defaultValue.toString();
            }
            if (shouldPersist()) {
                persistString(time);
            }
        }

        String[] timeParts=time.split(":");
        lastHour=Integer.parseInt(timeParts[0]);
        //lastMinute=Integer.parseInt(timeParts[1]);
    }

    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
        // Do something with the time chosen by the user




    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an instance of alarm manager and then create an intent for your service class  and a pending intent that will be based off a Calendar time so create an instance of calendar and assign it the time your user sets than set the Alar Manager to that Calendar.getInstance() as the code below shows.

```
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, 0);
    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis(), alarmIntent);
```

Comment: this is what i am doing in onTimeSet() method above but i have not mentioned it... But it is giving me error that you can not declare getSystemService Method in onTimeSet()..